# Add dropdown box in Google site

Tags: button, google-apps-script, web-applications, html-select, google-sites

I have some data in Google sheet.
How can i extract the data based on user request as per a dropdown box and generate it in **Google Site**.
The challenges iam faced with.

Prob_1- using a dropdown box in Google site

Prob_2- generate dynamic data ( or table ) in google site from the Google spreadsheet.

Analysis_1 - I have made a detailed study and understood that only using a third party plugin , i can make a select box. As a newbiew, needed some guidelines based on this.
Is it not possible without any third party plugin.

Analysis_2- Or is there any other option to generate an action based on a selection in google site. I understood that scripting is not possible in google site. So how shall i make a button click action.

Need some guidelines on this.

Comment: who told scripting is not possible in google site?

Comment: You can create a Google Apps Script which is published as a Web App.  You then use an iFrame to show the published web app.  Note that the New sites may not support this at this time.  In that case you would link and go to a new page.  Since the Web App can have HTML and CSS you could make it appear to be another page in teh site.

Comment: @Ritz : oh! so how shall i make dynamic changes using script. Google site allows button click actions?

Comment: @Karl_S : So in the Web App which is deployed as Html can have scripting inside it? Also i didnt get this point - **Note that the New sites may not support this at this time.**

Comment: The Web App is built with Google Apps Script which is based on JavaScript. there is Server and Client side scripting available.  There are two versions of Google Sites, ["Classic" and "New"](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/7176163?hl=en).  The last I looked the "New" sites did not have the ability to embed an iFrame or script.

Answer (score 2):

This is some javascript code to load options into a select box.

```
function updateSelect(vA)//array of values that go into the drop down or select box
{
  var select = document.getElementById("sel1");
  select.options.length = 0; 
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
  }
}
```

This is html for the select box.

```
 <select id="sel1" style="width:125px;height:35px;margin:10px 0 10px 0;">
      <option value="" selected></option>
   </select>
```

Seem pretty simple to me.

Here's a more complete solution.

Code:

```
function getSelectOptions()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Options');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var options=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    options.push(vA[i][0]);
  }
  return vA;
}

function showSidebar()
{
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('f');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'The Drop Down with No Options now has options.');
}
```

f.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#txt1').val('');
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateSelect)
          .getSelectOptions();
      });
    function updateSelect(vA)
    {
      var select = document.getElementById("sel1");
      select.options.length = 0; 
      for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
      {
        select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
      }
    }
    console.log("My code");
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <select id="sel1" style="width:125px;height:35px;margin:10px 0 10px 0;">
   </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here's what the sheet named Options

[image]

Comment: Inside the google sccript we can create this also? under script tag

Comment: Yes. I'll give you a complete working example of a google apps script program that I use everyday that has a dynamic drop down later this morning.

Comment: That was so helpful. I have great hope now.. When i tried i am getting this error @Cooper -  `Script function not found: doGet`

Comment: I didn't create a doGet.  I've been running it as a dialog. Look at the code you will see that. Can you write out the function in your answer  that you need to run to display the dialog